# Fill in dataframe column into separate percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a large dataframe that looks something like this:

```
ID   Fruit       Percentiles
001  Apple          0
002  Pear           0
003  Banana         0
004  Kiwi           0
005  Orange         0
006  Pineapple      0
...
...
039  Peach          0
040  Grapes         0
```

I want to create 40 different Percentiles (the data frame is already sorted, so I just need a way to fill the "Percentile" column)

The final Dataframe should look like this:

```
ID   Fruit       Percentile
001  Apple          1
002  Pear           1
003  Banana         2
004  Kiwi           2
005  Orange         3
006  Pineapple      3
...
...
039  Peach          40
040  Grapes         40
```

I have tried to create a loop which does something like this:

```
df.Category[0:int(df.size[0]*0.05)] = 1
df.Category[int(df.size[0]*0.05):int(df.size[0]*0.10)+1] = 2
...
...
df.Category[int(df.size[0]*0.95):int(df.size[0])+1] = 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) can be used on a RangeIndex to group into even sized groups:

```
df['Percentile'] = pd.cut(df.index, bins=20, labels=False) + 1
```

If the [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) is not already the default ascending zero based range index, we can use [pd.RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) based on the length of the DataFrame to generate one instead:

```
df['Percentile'] = pd.cut(pd.RangeIndex(len(df)), bins=20, labels=False) + 1
```

[np.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) works similarly:

```
df['Percentile'] = pd.cut(np.arange(len(df)), bins=20, labels=False) + 1
```

---

Some sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 40
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [f'{i:03d}' for i in range(1, n + 1)],
    'Fruit': np.random.choice(['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Orange'], n)
})
```

Comment: not sure what happened to `range(len(df))` in between. pd.RangeIndex damages readability for me